# dynamic insert layout with horizontal scoll view

Tags: android

[my image is here please show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wIDi.png)

Please help I need this type of customized layout for fetching a product image and there name from database.so I need created one than more layout while fetching data from server

NEED:
product name must be below to image.
product name and image are both in one layout but other second image and name to take new layout.same as first

Comment: You can use grid layout

Comment: how can I used gird layout? can you give me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this widget in your xml.

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/frg_home_categoryGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

    </GridView>
```

Than create inflater for this

```
      <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flexible_space_image_height"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/inf_categoryIv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inf_categoryTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/black_gradient"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin10"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Than after when you get the data you have to set adapter on [GridView tutorial](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Horizontal Scroll View then find below answer.

First Create Main XML file.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

      <HorizontalScrollView
              android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now create second custom layout file.

custom_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
          android:width="wrap_content"
          android:height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView" />

     <TextView
          android:width="wrap_content"
          android:height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Now on your .Java file implement coding for full fill images and add the view as sub view Horizontal Scroll View.

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private HorizontalScrollView hsv;
  private int IMAGES_RESOURCES[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
     addImages();

   }
}

public void addImages()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View subLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);
      TextView tv = (TextView) subLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) subLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    tv.setText("Cake " + i);
    imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES_RESOURCES[i]);

  hsv.addView(subLayout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you